# How do install AutoKey?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 16.04

How do I install autokey in the latest version of Ubuntu 16?

It isn't in the ubuntu software center.  How do I run a command line command to build such.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following command, copied and pasted into a Terminal window, should install autokey:

```
sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

Now I am no friend of the Software Center but the command line finds the package easily:

```
andrew@athens:~$ apt-cache search autokey
autokey-common - desktop automation utility - common data
autokey-gtk - desktop automation utility - GTK+ version
autokey-qt - desktop automation utility - KDE version
andrew@athens:~$
```

And trusty old Synaptic shows it clearly as well:

[image]

So perhaps follow my example and stick with these two :). The application installs fine from the command line on my Xenial installation:

[image]

**Note:** If testing this from a 'Live CD' you will need to enable the 'Universe' Repositories by following this path:

```
Dash --> Software & Updates --> Ubuntu Software
```

Then select the box 'Community-maintained free and open-source software (Universe).' Allow to reload and then install `autokey-gtk` as detailed previously...

**References:**

- [Package: autokey-gtk (0.90.4-1) [universe]](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/autokey-gtk)

Comment: Why doesn't it appear in the ubuntu software center?  I'm on windows at the moment and can't test this.

Comment: @LiamWilliam I rigorously avoid the Software Center and I think you shoud too :). Either commandline: `apt-cache search autokey` or the venerable old Synaptic are your best friends...

Comment: I'm still on windows right now but did you test the software?

Comment: @LiamWilliam I have installed it and attached a screenshot to my answer but not tested it extensively...

Comment: I have unaccepted this as answer because on16.04 this doesn't work.  What version are you own?

Comment: @LiamWilliam Just retested on Xenial: installs nicely. Do you have an error message when you install?

Comment: it doesn't appear in the search options when i type `apt-cache search autokey`  Might this be because I am running a live cd?

Comment: @LiamWilliam I see the issue: Universe Repository is not enabled by default  with LiveCD :). Look at Dash --> Software & Updates -->  Ubuntu Software and then select the box 'Community-maintained free and open-source software (Universe). Allow to reload and then all will be well.