# Emulate Numpad in linux

Tags: keyboard, numpad

My laptop does not have a numpad, not even those in which it is activated by the FN key.

When I was using windows, I used AutoHotkey with a script that I replaced  the QWEASDZXC keys by 789456123, and if I want to disable it just need to type F12.

Is there a way to do it in linux?

Comment: Try https://www.autohotkey.com/ and autkey(http://askubuntu.com/questions/801164/how-do-install-autokey)

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple ways to do this with XKB, but it's not for the faint of heart.

1. Make a [custom symbol option](https://superuser.com/a/1168603/685512) that adds your numbers to "level3" or "level5" of your chosen keys.  ([<kbd>AltGr</kbd>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr) is the `ISO_Level3_Shift` key, used in non-US or US-intl layouts for áçćéñþëd characters.)  Normally these keys act like <kbd>Shift</kbd> -- you'd have to hold them down while you typed the numbers.  But your new option could make them act more like <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> if preferred.  Such an option would then override your layout's default bindings for those letters to add the numbers.

   ```
   // emulate numpad on first 3 columns of alphabetic keys
   // initial key definitions from /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us
   // ("intl" stanza)
   partial 
   xkb_symbols "qweasdzxc" {

       // numbers on level3 (RightAlt chooses lv3)
       include "level3(ralt_switch)"
       key <AD01> { [ q, Q, 7, division ] };
       key <AD02> { [ w, W, 8, multiply ] };
       key <AD03> { [ e, E, 9,    minus ] };
       // etc ...

       // OR ...

       // numbers on level5 (RightCtrl chooses lv5)
       include "level5(rctrl_switch)"
       key <AD01> { [ q, Q, adiaeresis,  Adiaeresis,  7,  division ] };
       key <AD02> { [ w, W,      aring,       Aring,  8,  multiply ] };
       key <AD03> { [ e, E,     eacute,      Eacute,  9,     minus ] };
       // etc ...

   }; // end "qweasdzxc"


   // rules to load this as an option
   ! option         = symbols
     lv3:qweasdzxc  = +filename(qweasdzxc)


   // load from commandline. may need -I/path/to/custom/xkb
   setxkbmap -layout us -option lv3:qweasdzxc
   ```
2. Make an empty layout that emits only those numbers on those keys and no other alphanumeric symbols.  When loaded in as a second layout, you'd have a predefined layout-switch key and would use that to toggle between your main layout and this one.  Again, the layout-switch key could be configured like a <kbd>Shift</kbd> (only switch layouts while held) or a <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>.

   ```
   // emulate numpad on first 3 columns of alphabetic keys
   // leave other alphanumeric keys undefined
   // otherwise from /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us (basic stanza)
   default partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
   xkb_symbols "qweasdzxc" {

       name[Group1]= "Numpad Emulation";

       key <AD01> { [ 7, division ] }; // q
       key <AD02> { [ 8, multiply ] }; // w
       key <AD03> { [ 9,    minus ] }; // e

       key <AC01> { [ 4,        F ] }; // a
       key <AC02> { [ 5,        E ] }; // s
       key <AC03> { [ 6,        D ] }; // d

       key <AB01> { [ 1,        C ] }; // z
       key <AB02> { [ 2,        B ] }; // x
       key <AB03> { [ 3,        A ] }; // c
       // hexadecimal just for fun, replace if desired

   }; // end "qweasdzxc"


   // rules to load this as a layout
   ! layout         = symbols
     qweasdzxc      = qweasdzxc


   // load from commandline. may need -I/path/to/custom/xkb
   setxkbmap -layout us,qweasdzxc -option grp:caps_toggle
   ```

---

Either of these options can be implemented by altering system XKB files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/{symbols,rules}` or by storing your customizations in [local XKB configuration files](https://askubuntu.com/a/896297/669043).  Changes to the system files could be wiped out by an update to the `xkeyboard-config` package, but are easier to use with system layout setting tools like `/etc/default/keyboard` or GNOME's settings daemon.

Comment: :'( I want to do the same thing but I can't understand a lot of what's explained here. Can't find a good guide to XKB either