# For laptops that don't have a numpad, how can I create one?

Tags: keyboard, laptop, capslock, numpad

I've noticed when looking for a new 13" laptop from Dell, Lenovo, HP, etc, they do not have a Numpad - not even one working with the FN (function key).
I googled a lot, trying to find a way to make a laptop have a Numpad like they have on old computers on the function key.

For a laptop like the Dell XPS 13, is it possible to make like a CAPS LOCK options for the keys <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, and <kbd>L</kbd> act like <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, and <kbd>3</kbd>?

well the solution for me was to buy a thinkpad t580.
now i have the numpad :P

Comment: You might want to check out a [similar question here](https://askubuntu.com/q/899451/32664). Technically not a duplicate, as there was no official answer given, rather a couple of recommendations.

Comment: @richbl gave a link that suggests using xkb and AutoKey (in a comment). If you are using a graphic environment, then AutoKey https://github.com/autokey-py3/autokey would be the easiest way because it has a GUI front end which will make experimenting/configuration easier. xkb is fine, but harder to master (and will work where no GUI is installed.)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a 3rd party usb plug in numpad
there are a few on the market at about $40 
not the prettiest solution but would probably work

you may be able to install an alternate keyboard map and toggle it to a function key
combo (like ctl-caplock etc)

clive